# Azure blobs - Few larges or Multiple smalls

Tags: azure, blob

I'm creating a very large database of images on Azure, several TB's. The images are grouped in sets of about 150,000 images. Each images are pyramided and tiled which means about 60 chunks per image. So about a 1,000,000 chunks per set.

The images will never be accessed in their entirety, only specific chunks according to the required resolution (pyramid level) and the region of interest (tile) of the image.

For those of you who have extensive experimentation with Azure Blobs, would you recommend:

(A) Keep one big blob of 50GB and keep track of the position and length of each chunk externally (SQL Database) so you can later retrieve the chunk you need...

-OR-

(B) Create a 1,000,000 blobs of about 8KB in one container for the whole set and use the blob URI to retrieve the right chunk per convention.

B is more attractive to me but I worry that the indexing of those blobs by Azure will cause some lag to retrieve the blobs randomly accessed among 1,000,000's of them?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> (B) Create a 1,000,000 blobs of about 8KB in one container for the whole
>   set and use the blob URI to retrieve the right chunk per convention.

This would be my preference as well. Here're my reasons for doing it:

- **Scalability**: Each storage account has some scalability targets in terms of reads and writes and having separate blobs will give to ability to manage the scalability in a better way. With multiple blobs, you can spread them out in multiple storage accounts if needed to meet the scalability targets.
- **Maintainability**: With individual blobs approach, it is easier to maintain. You simply upload the blob, update the database and are done with it. With a single blob and storing the ranges someplace else, it can be problemmatic to maintain that. Let's consider an example: For the sake of simplicity let's assume that you only have 2 blobs - 1.png and 2.png. To begin with both of them are 8KB in size. So you create one blob (say blob.png) and store the ranges (0-8KB and 8KB-16KB) in the database. Now assume that you have to update 1.png and this time the size is 10KB. You simply can't write that blob in the bigger blob as now you need to push back 2.png as it's starting point is now 10KB mark. Now extend that to 1000s of blob. Updating a blob can become real cumbersome in this scenario and I am not sure if it's worth doing it that way.

> B is more attractive to me but I worry that the indexing of those
>   blobs by Azure will cause some lag to retrieve the blobs randomly
>   accessed among 1,000,000's of them?

Regarding your comment about indexing, Azure indexes blobs by blob name so as long as you're directly accessing the blob by its URL, you should not encounter indexing issues.

You may find this article useful for understanding Azure Storage Scalability and Performance Targets: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. One point though. The 150,000 images are static, known, and the set is complete at the time of the upload. So the maintainability argument is not a consideration in my use-case.
I have read the Azure Storage Scalability and Performance Targets but my nose is still scratching at the idea having azure index millions of blobs.

Comment: @Martin - Azure doesn't index any blobs. They are simply accessed by direct URI. The only indexing done is by you, if using a separate database engine to accomplish this.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Please see this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/#partitions-in-azure-storage. From what I understand (and I may be wrong), Partitioning provides faster access to a storage item (and thus somewhat similar to indexing).

Comment: @GauravMantri I'm referring specifically to the notion of database indexing, a time- and resource-intensive activity in a database system, and something that doesn't exist with blob storage (partitioning isn't the same as indexing). I felt the OP was thinking about *indexing* the wrong way in this case, per the comment above.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks! I completely agree with your comment about indexing.

Comment: By indexing I mean somewhere on the Azure infrastructure the URI to physical blob is indexed somewhere. I can assure you they don't put 1,000,000 blobs in a folder on disk and find the right file by convention.